# Facebook Invite Share Dialog not Opening iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-invite-friends

can anyone help me with it:
I have configured the facebook invite feature. I have a button on which I have written the code to open the facebook invite dialog. I have also uploaded the file to the server.
But when I click on the button to open the dialog.
I am getting these errors
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 9.)
TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044509/error-in-sending-app-invitation-in-ios-to-facebook-friends

Comment: @Muneeb Rehman are you solved your problem getting same issue

Comment: No. I read that Facebook has finished the support for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Facebook had deprecated its AppInvite feature](https://blog.getsocial.im/facebook-deprecates-app-invites-are-you-ready/#acquisition) in Feb, and just a few days back it also deprecated its Invitable friends API (read more [here](https://blog.getsocial.im/deprecation-of-facebook-invitable-friends-graph-api-and-its-impact-on-organic-growth/)). If you have a gaming app you can continue to use the Game Request dialog.

We have written about the alternatives you have in the articles above.

Disclaimer: I am the founder of GetSocial

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.0, Please follow the tutorial below.

[Facebook, Messenger - Photo, Video, Link sharing in iOS Swift.](https://mahmudul-razib.medium.com/facebook-messenger-photo-video-link-sharing-in-ios-swift-465ef1388471)